# The user posted a question in StackOverFlow and suddenly forgot his/her password. Because of that he/she can't update his/her post

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I came across with [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15497708/109702) (10K only) in Stack Overflow where in an user posted a question the suddenly lost and forgot his/her password, as the result he can't open his/her account and update the post.

[image]

How do you(moderators) deal it in StackOverFlow? given that he/she utterly forget anything about his/her account information and somehow cannot retrieve it. Can I flag this post then tell the user to re-post it to his/her new account?

Comment: Really, registered 2 days ago and forgot their email address? 10minutemail.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
if (sufficientRep)  
    edit the question and add what was posted in the answer

flag answer for mod attention
```

(sorry, I couldn't resist, the way I originally typed my answer I may as well have done it this way....)

Make sure you use the custom flag reason. In your case you don't have sufficient rep, so just flag it. You could try a suggested edit but you stand a good chance that it would get declined.

Comment: A suggested edit should work if the description is clear enough about what's going on, shouldn't it?

Comment: @TRiG: could, be I'd recommend against it. Especially since that non-answer could get deleted between the moment the suggestion is made and the moment it is reviewed. Not all reviewers have the 10k rep necessary to verify the edit.

Comment: FWIW, in this circumstance the user [suggested an edit to his post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1748370) *after* posting the non-answer, and it was close to getting accepted (yes, even with the horrendous formatting).